# RegEx to allow all characters, length should be 1-50 characters

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to implement a *regular expression* that will check a string is between 1 - 50 characters. They are allowed to enter any characters.

I am new to creating regex expressions, but this is my attempt: `^{1,50}$`

The reason I tried that is that I found this was the way to limit the characters.

Comment: What character are you allowing ?

Comment: @noob To allow all characters

Comment: `.` will match any one character, so `^.{1,50}$`

Comment: `^.{1,50}$` - you missed the dot. But I'm pretty sure that C# has methods to check string length without using regex.

Comment: Why do you need regex, can you not just check the length of the string?

Comment: Why not just put `MyString.Length <= 50`?

Comment: We use a validation engine which is done with regex to keep all validation in one place.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try `^.{1,50}$`

**Explanation:**

- `.` dot stands for all characters. Except `\n` for which you will have to use `s` DOTALL flag.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hU9hI6/3)**

**[Regular Expression Options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs(v=vs.110).aspx)**

Answer (score 19):

For the **exact length** of the string, you could use

```
^.{50}$
```

Whereas to check the **length range** you can use

```
^.{5,50}$
```

It might be more sensible for real users if I also included a lower limit on the number of letters.

If you wanted to just check the **minimum length** you can use

```
^.{50,}$
```

Now a string of at least fifty letters, but extending to any length,

```
^.{0,50}$
```

This will match a whole string containing between 0 and 50 (inclusive) of any character. Though regular expressions are probably the wrong tool for this job. **Regex is overkill**; just check the length of the string. You should have used `String.Length` for this, like:

```
if(UrString.Length > 0 && UrString.Length <= 50)
```

Answer (score 2):

To allow all characters, you use `.` in regex.

So, to have a maximum 50 character string, you'd do:

```
^.{1,50}$
```

Answer (score 2):

Just inspect the [`Length`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.length(v=vs.110).aspx) of the string:

```
string str = "less than 50 characters";
if(str.Length > 0 && str.Length <= 50)
{
    // Yay, we've got a winner
}
```

Comment: @noob yes, this will work on multiline strings as well (but each newline char will count towards the length)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest

`.{1,50}`

To generate regex expressions you can use [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/expresso.htm), which is a free .NET regular expression development tool. Using this program, you will be able to build complex regular expressions just by selecting its different components from a menu. You can test the created expressions entering values to them.

Comment: If you have 60 characters it will match first 50 and leave remaining 10. The entire string has to be within range. Adding anchors will solve this problem like this [^.{1,50}$](https://regex101.com/r/hU9hI6/3)